# jquery autocomplete multi element how to append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I need select many data for one item.

in this case, I will select some game for relation one page.

I dont know how many game. So, I do that.

But I dont know how to submit the ID , not the value.name?

```
function AddElement(mytype){ 
  var mytype,TemO=document.getElementById("add"); 
  var newInput = document.createElement("input");  
  newInput.type=mytype;
  newInput.name="game[]"; 
  newInput.className="select_game"; 
  newInput.placeholder="select game";
  TemO.appendChild(newInput); 
  var newline= document.createElement("br");   

  var mytype,TemO=document.getElementById("add"); 
  var newInput = document.createElement("input");  
  newInput.type=mytype;
  newInput.name="gameid[]"; 
  newInput.placeholder="Game ID";
  TemO.appendChild(newInput); 
  var newline= document.createElement("br"); 
  TemO.appendChild(newline); 


  $(function() {

    $( ".select_game" ).autocomplete({
      source: "select.php",
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).next().find('gameid[]').first().append(data); // Here I need help
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I get these json data

```
[{value: "lol", id: 11}, {value: "wow", id: 10}]
```

Now if I select `lol,wow,`

my php will be get game[]=lol,wow,

but I need to get gameid[]=11,10

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit the id, only names and values are sent. What you can do is create a function to run before submit (maybe give the submit button `onclick=foo()`) and make this function get your inputs and set their name to their IDs. You might use this code:

```
function foo()
{
    $("[name]").each(function(idx, dom)
    {
        dom.id = dom.name;
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a JS Novice

I do not understand this logic
I added this function() in JS, it's not any effect

Comment: can I append the json data ID to gameid[] input ??

Comment: You must pass it to the submit input in the HTML like this: `<input type=submit value=Submit onclick=foo()>`

Comment: Btw in the last line I believe you mean to say `.find(["name='gameid[]'"])`